# prism InvokeCommandAction behaviour ignoring IsEnabled property (possible bug?)

Tags: c#, prism

I am trying to get to the bottom of why the IsEnabled property of a checkbox is being ignored when using the prism InvokeCommandAction behaviour.

Essentially, if I use the standard InvokeCommandAction behaviour then everything works fine, but if I switch to the prism InvokeCommandAction, then the IsEnabled property is ignored.

To replicate this, I took the Commanding Quickstart from prism and changed the OrdersEditorView to this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView AutomationProperties.AutomationId="OrderListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" SelectionMode="Single" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessOrderCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="Key"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:OrderViewModel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <CheckBox IsEnabled="False" Content="Prism" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessOrderCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsEnabled="False" Content="Interactivity">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessOrderCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

So I've just wrapped the original ListView in a stack panel and added two checkboxes that bind the existing ProcessOrderCommand command to the InvokeCommandAction behaviour.  The checkbox using the interactivity InvokeCommandAction is correctly disabled (the IsEnabled property is correctly set to False), but the checkbox using the  prism InvokeCommandAction is enabled, even though the IsEnabled property is set to false.

Now this is just a basic example, in real life the behaviour is passing parameters to the command (which is why I want to use the prism version) and the IsEnabled property is bound to a property on a ViewModel.  I've just reduced this example to its most basic elements. However this is such very specific strange behaviour, surely I'm doing something wrong here?  This can't be a bug in prism can it?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a little old, but today a co-worker and I ran into the same issue at work, so we did ask to StackOverflow and we couldn't find the solution. After we figure it out, we decided to post the solution here in case someone else encounters this kind of problem in the future.

As @Georg Piwonka says, that behavior is by design in Prism, but you can use the property you are binding to and after raising the PropertyChanged event, then call the RaiseCanExecuteChanged method of the command in order to reevaluate the CanExecute method you used when created your command.

So, let say you have OrderProcessingViewModel class containing a ProcessOrderCommand command (DelegateCommand)

```
public class OrderProcessingViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs> ProcessOrderCommand;
    private string targetProperty;

    public OrderProcessingViewModel()
    {
        ProcessOrderCommand = new DelegateCommand<KeyEventArgs>(ProcessOrder, CanProcessOrder);
    }

    private Order OrderToProcess { get; set; }

    public string TargetProperty
    {
        get { return targetProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(targetProperty, value))
            {
                targetProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TargetProperty");

                //IMPORTANT: Let the delegate command to call its CanExecute method so we can update the Enabled property.
                ProcessOrderCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CanProcessOrder(KeyEventArgs arg)
    {
        //TODO: Here you check when to enable or disable the check box
        var mustEnable = OrderToProcess != null;

        //The value returned from this method is the result assigned to the IsEnable property for the command's related object
        return mustEnable;
    }

    private void ProcessOrder(KeyEventArgs obj)
    {
        //Do the stuff to process the order
    }
}
```

The key concept here is not to go against Prism. If you want to enable the related control whenever the target property changes, you should re-run the CanExcecute method for the DelegateCommand command.

Prism has a mechanism for that purpose, the only thing you need to do is to call the RaiseCanExecuteChanged for the ProcessOrderCommand command and if the result of the method is true, the related control, in this case the Checkbox will be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Prism has changed the standard behaviour. The standard behaviour is to bind the Enabled property of the UI element to the CanExecute property of the command, unless the Enabled property has been set separately. In which case, they operate independently.  Prism changed this behaviour by not allowing independent operation of the Enabled property when the UI element is bound to a Prism command. It is a subtle difference, but the Prism method is less flexible

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right. 
It seems that is behavior is by design of the prism InvokeCommandAction. 
prism InvokeCommandAction cals the CanExecute method on the DelegateCommand and sets the IsEnabled property with return value of this function. So the upper IsEnabled is ignored. The same behavior is in the Button Command Property, which sets the IsEnabled according to the CanExecute method of the Command.